# Problem with free function in C for pointers

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have two pointers and I want to fill the pointer `somme` with the values ​​contained in the pointer `v`.

This is method:

```
somme[0]=v[0] + v[1];
somme[1]=v[2] + v[3];
somme[2]=v[4] + v[5];

...
```

The error occurs when it performs the `distruggi_vec(somme);` function and not `distruggi_vec(v);`.

do you have any ideas? Thank you for your time.

This is my c code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t *crea_vec(size_t  n)
{
    uint32_t *p;
    p = malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    return p;
}

uint32_t *somme_2a2(uint32_t *vett, size_t size) 
{
    if (size % 2 != 0) 
    {
        size = size - 1;
    }

    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        if (i >= 10) { goto a; }
        j = i * 2;
        vett[i] = vett[j] + vett[j + 1];
    }
    a:
    size = size / 2;
    vett = realloc(vett, size * sizeof(uint32_t));

    return vett;
}

extern void distruggi_vec(uint32_t *p)
{
    free(p);
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 20;
    uint32_t *v = crea_vec(n);
    uint32_t *somme = somme_2a2(v, n);
    distruggi_vec(v);
    distruggi_vec(somme);

    return 0;
}
```

when I debug my code it gives me this problem:
[image]

Comment: Don't use `goto` to break out of a loop, use `break`.

Comment: `distruggi_vec` has the function to deallocate the pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used goto because I wanted to see if it was break the problem, but in the end it was not the problem

Comment: Simple remove `distruggi_vec(somme);`. There might be other problems too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your time, this is the final solution of my problem without errors:

Code:

`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t *crea_vec(size_t  n)
{
    uint32_t *p;
    p = malloc(n * sizeof(uint32_t));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    return p;
}

uint32_t *somme_2a2(uint32_t *vett, size_t size) 
{
    uint32_t *vett2 = calloc(size/2, sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (size % 2 != 0) 
    {
        size = size - 1;
    }

    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        if (i >= 10) { break; }
        j = i * 2;
        vett[i] = vett[j] + vett[j + 1];
        vett2[i] = vett[i];
    }

    return vett2;
}

extern void distruggi_vec(uint32_t *p)
{
    free(p);
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 20;
    uint32_t *v = crea_vec(n);
    uint32_t *somme = somme_2a2(v, n);
    distruggi_vec(v);
    distruggi_vec(somme);

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: Allocating momory for a separate result array in `somme_2a2` is what I would have proposed. If `vett2 == NULL` you should not try to save data in `vett2` and make sure you return `NULL` from `somme_2a2`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't write code like

```
 vett = realloc(vett, size * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

in case `realloc()` fails, you'll lose the original pointer, too.

From the `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> If memory for the new object cannot be
>   allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

and

> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

Always catch the return value of `realloc()` in a temp pointer, check it against `NULL` and if it is valid, you can (optionally) assign it back to the original pointer. Something like (pseudocode)

```
pointer temp = NULL;
temp = realloc (oldPOinter, size);
if (!temp) 
{
    printf ("Some error message");
    return SOME_ERROR_CODE;
}
oldPOinter = temp;
```

That said, the problem here, is, in case `realloc()` is success, the original pointer is no longer to be used. `v` is passed to `somme_2a2()` as an argument, and as per C, it's pass by value. Thus, any change made to `vett` will not reflect back to the caller in `v`.

However, since the `realloc()` changes the validity of the memory pointer to by `vett`, after returning successfully from the `somme_2a2()` call, in the `main()`, `v` is not  valid anymore, and you don't need to pass that to `free()`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. [...]

Passing `vett` to `free()` will cause undefined behavior, because you'll end up attempting to `free()` a pointer which has already been `free()`-d [via success of `realloc()`].

Quoting chapter §7.22.3.3

> [...] if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks, got myself confused,

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many calls to `realloc` you make, you will still only have *one* pointer: The one *last* returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

After the call to `realloc` the original pointer becomes invalid, and you should only use the pointer it returns.

That means when you call `distruggi_vec` with the invalid pointer `v` you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Oh wow I did not think about it thank you, but  how can I not delete the original pointer? Do I have to create a support pointer right?

Comment: @KKKKK The `realloc` takes care of any freeing that needs to be done. Once you have called `realloc`, just don't use the original pointer *value* that you passed to `realloc`.

Comment: Thank you very much